# Can't paste data from SQL into Excel

Tags: sql, ssms-2014

I created code in SQL to get specific data.

However, when I try to paste the results into Excel, I get an error message that says

"Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data."

Has anyone experienced this? If so, do you know what the solution is?

I modified the code to only extract data from one department (instead of 4), to reduce the number of rows from just under 1 million to 153,671 rows, but I still get the same error message. The data has 12 columns.

Your help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: can you be more specific about "pasting" ?
are you trying to copy using automatic tools, or doing a regular ctrl c ctrl v ?

Comment: Instead of a simple copy | paste, have you tried exporting your data to MS Excel?

Comment: I assume you are doing ctrl c ctrl v. The cache which copies the data can't paste 153K rows. I suggest you to export the result set via ouptut window.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you all for your responses. Yes, I was trying to ctrl c then ctrl v. I'll tryto export the data instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the keyboard shortcut (ctrl+C, ctrl+V), I guess it's previsible that It can't work, because event if the interface can look like excel, the data is different.

you can do the same using automatic tools that will do the query for you and put the result in a csv / excel document.

If you are using MSSQL, you can look on other MS tools such as SSDT, which is very simple to use and have tools to exchange excel data to (or from) SQL databases

another way is to connect your excel sheet to your database. this is explained on MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy and paste that many rows at a time due to cache restraints. Your best bet is export the query result to a csv file and open it in excel. Here's how to do it:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Go to Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results To Text
3. On the far right, there is a drop down box called Output Format
4. Choose Comma Delimited and click OK

From here it'll show your query results as comma-delimited text.
To save the results of your query to a file: Ctrl + Shift + F

Comment: Hi DarthTommy, thanks for the prompt response. Didn't know that you couldn't copy and paste that much data! I tried the route you suggested above,but my path is a bit different. I'll try to add a screenshot to this comment.